# How can I get value of the nested dictionary using ImmutableMultiDict on Flask?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

```
address_dict = {'address': {'US': 'San Francisco', 'US': 'New York', 'UK': 'London'}}
```

When above parameters was sent via requests, how can I get values in address key using request.form on Flask?

```
import requests
url =  'http://example.com'
params = {"address": {"US": "San Francisco", "UK": "London", "CH": "Shanghai"}}
requests.post(url, data=params)
```

Then I got this in context of flask.request.

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('address', u'US'), ('address', 'US'), ('address', 'UK')])
```

How can I get the value in each key of addresses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

for example like this:

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
imd = ImmutableMultiDict([('address', u'US'), ('address', 'US'), ('address', 'UK')])
print imd.getlist('address')
```

prints:

```
[u'US', 'US', 'UK']
```

---

edit:

Your POST-request is sent [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1), which means as combination as key/value pairs. It doesn't support a nested dict structure directly. When i try your curl-request I get this:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('address[US]', u'San Francisco'), ('address[US]', u'New York'), ('address[UK]', u'London')])
```

so the keys are interpreted literally here.

and using `urllib2` i get this result:

```
>>> print urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost:5000/post", data=urllib.urlencode(address_dict)).read()
ImmutableMultiDict([('address', u"{'UK': 'London', 'US': 'New York'}")])
```

here `urlencode` simply sends a string representation of the inner dict.

and finally using `requests`:

```
>>> print requests.post("http://localhost:5000/post", data=address_dict).content
ImmutableMultiDict([('address', u'UK'), ('address', u'US')])
```

here the array is flattened and recurring keys eliminated.

There is simply no defined way how to send a nested dict like yours in an urlencoded way, so you'll have to find another solution.

Comment: Is there any way to get 'San Francisco' in above example? I mean value of dict in parent dict.

Comment: That information don't seem to be in the dict... I'm not sure you can send a dict like this... have to check it... How do you send the post request?

Comment: I send the post request via curl. Sorry for lack of explanation. I would like to get values(San Francisco, New York, London) from address dict.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to use dict instead of MultiDict in this case. I try to find solution.

Answer (score 2):

You gave this example:

```
curl http://example.com -d "address[US]=San Francisco" -d "address[US]=New York" -d address[UK]=London"
```

With such a request, `request.form` would look like this:

```py
>>> request.form
ImmutableMultiDict([('address[US]', u'San Francisco'), ('address[US]', u'New York'),
                    ('address[UK]', u'London')])
>>> request.form['address[US]']
u'San Francisco'
>>> request.form.getlist('address[US]')
[u'San Francisco', u'New York']
```

The `[` and `]` characters are not special, they are just part of the keys. [As documented](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict), a MultiDict will map each key not just to one value but to a list of values. Normal dictionnary access with [] will only give you the first key, but the getlist() method gives the whole list for one key. Other methods are available, see the docs.

If you really want a nested structure, try JSON instead of flat form data.